# How to get the correct bounding box of a 3D model just after loading it in three.js

Tags: three.js

I am trying to obtain the bounding box of a glTF 3D model in three.js.
I realised that the bounding box is incorrect if it is computed just after the model has been loaded. If we wait a moment before getting the bounding box, then it is correct.

```js
const loader = new GLTFLoader();
loader.load(modelUrl, (gltf) => {

  const model = gltf.scene;
  model.position.x = -0.15;
  scene.add(model);

  // This shows a wrong bounding box (yellow)
  const box = new THREE.BoxHelper(model, 0xffff00);
  scene.add(box);
});

loader.load(modelUrl, (gltf) => {

  const model = gltf.scene;
  model.position.x = 0.15;
  scene.add(model);

  // This shows the correct bounding box (red)
  setTimeout(() => {
    const box = new THREE.BoxHelper(model, 0xff0000);
    scene.add(box);
  }, 100);
});
```

See code example: [glitch threejs bounding box sample](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/obvious-painted-mammal)

Why is the bounding box not correct initially and what is the correct way to get the 3D model bounding box without using `setTimeout`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The model you load has a series of intricate Object3D with multiple transformations (possibly scale and/or translate).
2. That means that the computation for the bounding box at the first frame is "wrong" for the current `Scene`. You can replace the `setTimeout` (that actually fails if your browser is lagging and end up with a red box that is also wrong) by a `requestAnimationFrame` that would be more precise. The reason for this is because there is a property `.matrixAutoUpdate` (that is `true` by default) that tells that the next frame will recomputed the matrix but the first one has the "wrong" state.
3. You can force that computation of the model matrix (and all of its descendants) by using [`.updateMatrixWorld()`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/core/Object3D.updateMatrixWorld)

Working example:
https://glitch.com/edit/#!/whispering-snapdragon-expansion?path=script.js%3A44%3A0

Comment: You gave him a solution. Good for you and good for him.

Answer (score -1):

Because in the "yellow" case the model is not fully loaded and the bounding box performs calculations based on what is. In the "red" case, the situation is different, but only because you set `setTimeout`, which allows calculations to be made on the "full" model. If you don't want to use `setTimeout` (which in my opinion is right, because there are several factors that influence the model loading speed, and you can't make it a constant value), you can use `onLoad` or `loadAsync`.

```
const loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
async function loadSpider() {
  const gltf = await loader.loadAsync(modelUrl);
  const spider = gltf.scene;
  spider.position.x = -0.15;
  scene.add(spider);
  const box = new THREE.BoxHelper(model, 0xff0000);
  scene.add(box);
}
loadSpider();
```

or

```
const loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
loader.load(modelUrl, (gltf) => {
  const spider = gltf.scene;
  spider.position.x = -0.15;
  scene.add(spider);
  gltf.scene.traverse((child) => {
    if (child.isMesh) {
      const box = new THREE.BoxHelper(child, 0xff0000);
      scene.add(box);
    }
  });
});
```

If you ask, which is better, like (usually) this depend on individual (project) factors.

Comment: What you suggest is no different from what I do. It does not work.
I don't like using setTimeout because we don't know exactly what the timeout delay should be.

Comment: Please read carefully what I wrote earlier, I am not suggesting that you should use setTimeout, on the contrary.

Comment: The model is fully loaded. The matter is about first frame matrix calculation and has nothing to do with the loading speed.